# Is there a way to send message as a user (not as a bot) when using slash command in Slack API?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Hi I want to add functionality to our slack app that when slash command is used, it posts message from the actual command executer (not from a bot)

for example
if person Foo Bar posts message using slash command `/treats` in channel where app bot invited as below
`/treats thank you @jon_doe for your help`
and expected message is
`Foo Bar : thank you @jon_doe for your help`
not like
`MY APP BOT : thank you @jon_doe for your help`

do I need to store every user's token and use accordingly in `client.chat.postMessage` or is there safer, simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to post a message from a user is to use the user's token and call the `chat.postMessage` method.

Yes, you will need to store every user's token if you would like your app to be able to post on every user's behalf.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).